# Two independent sequences in $l_\infty$ that are bounded by $1$, and their sum is bounded by $2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Prove that there are $2$ independent vectors $x,y \in(l_\infty)$ such that $||x||=||y||=1$ and $||x+y||=2$
>
> (Here $l_\infty = \{(a_n)|a_n\in \mathbb{C}, sup|a_n|<\infty\}$ and $||x||=sup|x_n|$).

I was thinking about the following -

$x=(x_n)=(1-\frac{1}{n})$, $y=(y_n)=1$.

It is easy to see that $||x||=||y||=1$, and also that $||x+y||=||1-\frac{1}{n}+1||=2$.

What I'm not sure is, are $x,y$ independent?

(My definition of being independent - $x_1,x_2,...,x_n\in E$ are independent in $E_0$ if: $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_ix_i \in E_0 \iff\alpha_i=0 \forall 1\le i \le n$).

Comment: Why not just $x=(x_n)=(1-\delta_{0n})$? And try taking your formula for independence and writing out the sum explicitly for $n=2$.

Comment: @jgon What's the difference between your $x$ and mine?

Comment: nothing important really, both work, just for some reason it feels like an easier example to me, so I was curious as to why you chose the one you did. The helpful part of my comment was supposed to be the second sentence.

Comment: @jgon So when writing out the formula, I get that $\alpha_1 -\frac{\alpha}{n} + \alpha_2=0$. Since we are stuck with the $n$(i.e., it won't disappear for the equation) can I conclude that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$?

Comment: note that that formula must hold in particular when $n=1$, which gives us $\alpha_2=0$, and when $n=2$, which gives us $\frac{1}{2}\alpha_1+\alpha_2=0$. Solving this system of equations gives us $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=0$.